# Get user coarse coordinates - latest method

Tags: android, google-api, gps, android-gps

I am a bit confused about getting the latest user coordinates as Google updated more or less recently its API and I can find only old answers to old questions about this topic and none of those works to me.

Studying the Official API documents I wrote such a function:

```
if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( (Activity) MainActivity.this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23 )
{

    FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient( ( Activity ) MainActivity.this );
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener( ( Activity) MainActivity.this,
                                                                new OnSuccessListener<Location>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location)
        {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if ( location != null )
            {
                lastLocation    =   location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    }
    );
}
```

I am testing on a emulator running Android 4.0 and - anyways - the permission part is fully working to fit Android 6.0 but still can't get the latest coordinates.
I run my function within Asynctask process which is supposed to return the data - without succeeding.

Any help please to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Firstly, When you test location I suggest you use a 'real' device for better/real data because the emulator by default returns a hard-coded data... Secondly, no need for an AsyncTask because getLastLocation already happens in the background. Otherwise your code looks like it's supposed to work.

Comment: Also apart from AsyncTask process it returns back null value... I am working on a test app firstly and trying to figure out where's the problem

Comment: It is stated in the docs (https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) that sometimes the returned value can be null.. Maybe the requestLocationUpdates api is more suitable for you: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html